# $1\otimes \arccos \frac{1}{3}$ is not zero in  $\mathbb{R}{\otimes}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

How to prove that the element
$1\otimes \arccos\frac{1}{3}\in\mathbb{R}{\otimes}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q})$ isn't equal to zero?

I know why
$$\arccos\frac{1}{3}\neq \frac{m}{n}\pi,$$
where $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

So, am I right that sufficiently state on $\mathbb{R}{\otimes}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q})$ (on decomposable elements) equivalence relation
$$x\otimes y \sim x\otimes z \Leftrightarrow (y-z)\in\mathbb{Q}?$$

Thanks.

Comment: Could you rephrase your last sentence?  I don't understand the English grammar.

Comment: Oops, I mean the 2nd-to-last sentence.  The sentence "Thanks." is fine. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The hypothesis that $\arccos\frac{1}{3}\neq \frac{m}{n}\pi$ is irrelevant. What counts is that $\arccos\frac{1}{3}\notin \mathbb Q$.

Choose a basis $(r_i)_{i\in I}$ of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ with $0\in I$ and $x_0=1$.
Every $\xi \in \mathbb{R}{\otimes}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q})$ can be written **uniquely** as $\xi=\Sigma x_i\otimes \bar y_i$ and in particular $$1\otimes \bar y_i=0 \iff \bar y_i=0 \in \mathbb R/\mathbb{Q}\iff   y_i\in \mathbb Q$$
which proves that $1\otimes \overline {\arccos\frac{1}{3}}\neq 0$

Comment: $@$Georges: I was about to type out a similar answer, but I was stymied at giving a reference for the irrationality of $\arccos \frac{1}{3}$.  Do you know of one?

Comment: @Pete: This has been asked and answered in [a separate question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111288/why-arccos-frac13-is-an-irrational-number).

Comment: Thanks a lot to Pete:  he  was absolutely right to raise the issue. Indeed I didn't know a reference for the irrationality of $\arccos\frac{1}{3}$ and I am extremely grateful to @joriki for providing one.

Comment: Dear Georges: Thank you very much for your comment. I deleted my answer. I feel at the same time very embarrassed and very grateful, ... but more grateful than embarrassed, so positive feelings win! (By the way I was the first one of a hopefully very long list of users upvoting *your* answer. I liked it already when I believed mine was correct...)

Comment: @Pierre-Yves:  If you don't mind my asking, what was wrong with your original post?  I remember reading it and thinking to myself "yes, that makes sense", then running off to class.

Comment: Dear @Jason: I undeleted the answer. Thanks for you kind comment.

Comment: @joriki: thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**WARNING!!!** As explained in Georges's comment, the argument below is **completely wrong**. After having read this comment I deleted the answer, but Jason asked me very kindly what precisely was incorrect. So I decided to undelete it, hoping that it will serve as an example of what one should **not** do. (I hope the warning is conspicuous enough. If it isn't, please let me know.)

Hint. The tensor $1\otimes a\in\mathbb R\otimes_\mathbb Q\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ is nonzero if and only if $a$ is irrational.

Proof: The natural $\mathbb Q$-bilinear map $f$ from $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ sends $(1,a)$ to $a$.

(The map $f$ is defined, with obvious notation, by $f(x,\overline y)=\overline{xy}$.)

Edit. More generally, the argument shows this. Let $A$ be a subring of $B$. Then $1\otimes\overline b$ is zero in $B\otimes_AB/A$ if an only if $b$ is in $A$. (We assume that $B$ is commutative.)

Comment: Dear Pierre-Yves, I'm afraid the map $f$ is not well defined. Indeed, it would lead to  $f(\pi,\bar 0)=\bar 0=f(\pi,\bar 1)=\overline {\pi}\neq \bar 0$

Comment: That really is a subtle error!  Thank you again for undeleting it.