# Why $\arccos(\frac{1}{3})$ is an irrational number?

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry

I was reading the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111258/module-mathbbr-otimes-mathbbq-mathbbr-mathbbq). It is a very nice question with a very nice answer! I would like to know why $\arccos(\frac{1}{3})$ is an irrational number.

Comment: See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=ov-IlIEo47cC&pg=PA17&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a consequence of a [result of Ivan Niven](http://books.google.com/books?id=ov-IlIEo47cC&pg=PA21&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false): The trigonometric functions are irrational at non-zero rational values of the arguments.

Particularly, your question is addressed by the corollary to the above (Corollary 2.8 in the link):  any non-zero value of an inverse trigonometric function is irrational for a rational value of the argument.

Comment: See also [this blog post](http://someclassicalmaths.wordpress.com/2009/07/17/nivens-proof-that-the-trigonometric-and-inverse-trigonometric-functions-are-irrational-for-rational-non-zero-arguments/) that presents the proof.