# How do i prove that $\frac{1}{\pi} \arccos(1/3)$ is irrational?

Tags: trigonometry, irrational-numbers

How do i prove that $\frac{1}{\pi} \arccos(1/3)$
 is irrational?

Comment: This appears to have a solution: http://www.math.utk.edu/~jconant/pisol.html (along with this hint: http://www.math.utk.edu/~jconant/pihint2.html)

Comment: This question have been answered here: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111288/why-arccos-frac13-is-an-irrational-number)

Comment: Am I right in thinking you mean $\Big(\arccos(1/3)\Big)/\pi$ and not $\arccos\Big((1/3)/\pi\Big)$?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let $\theta = \arccos\dfrac13$ so that $\cos\theta=\dfrac13$.

If $\theta$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$, say $\theta=\dfrac mn \pi$, then $\cos(n\theta)=\pm1$.  Now $\cos(n\theta)=T_n(\cos\theta)$, where $T_n$ is the $n$th-degree [Chebyshev polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).  Using mathematical induction and some trigonometric identities, you can show that the leading coefficient in the $n$th-degree Chebyshev polynomial is $2^{n-1}$ for $n\ge2$.  We have
$$
\pm1=T_n\left(\frac 13\right) = 2^{n-1}\left(\frac13\right)^n+\text{lower-degree terms}.
$$
Multiplying both sides by $3^n$, we get
$$
\pm3^n = 2^{n-1} + \text{terms divisible by $3$}.
$$
And that says a positive power of $2$ is a multiple of $3$, which violates uniqueness of prime factorizations.

Comment: Nice solution....Michael Hardy...

Comment: @juantheron : Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Let’s call this angle $\Theta$. If it were rational, then there would be an $N$ such that $\cos(N\Theta)=1$. That would say that $\cos\Theta$ was a root of $T_N-1$, where $T_N$ is the appropriate Čebyšev polynomial, which it can’t be ’cause it’s transcendental.

Comment: This seems to assume that what was intended was $\arccos\Big((1/3)/\pi\Big)$.  If that's what was intended, then this answer is right.  I posted an answer that is right if $\dfrac{\arccos(1/3)}{\pi}$ was intended.  The latter seems more plausible, since if the former was intended, then it could have said $(1/(3\pi))$ rather than having fractions within fractions.

Comment: I meant $\frac{1}{\pi} \arccos(1/3)$. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: Are you saying $\Theta=\dfrac1\pi\arccos(1/3)$, or $\Theta=\arccos(1/3)$.  In the latter case, $\cos\Theta$ is rational.  In the former case, why should $\cos\Theta$ be a root of $T_N-1$?

Comment: When in doubt, use parentheses! Thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 1):

I try to use induction method without using  Chebyshev polynomial. We want to show that for $\cos\pi\alpha=\frac{1}{3}$, then $\alpha$ is irrational.

Let $\alpha=\frac{r}{s}$ where $r,s\in \mathbb Z$ and $s>0$, hence amoung $\cos(n\pi\alpha)$ we have at most $2s$ numbers. Since $\cos\pi\alpha=\frac{1}{3}$, hence by $\cos2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1$ we arrive to $\cos(2^m\pi\alpha)=\frac{t}{3^{2^{m-1}}}$ which $3\nmid t$. and $t\in \mathbb Z$. So we have infinity numbers of $\cos(2^m\pi\alpha)$ which are different together.  Hence $\alpha$ must be irrational.

Answer (score -1):

$$\alpha :=\arccos\left ( \frac{1}{3}\right )$$
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\alpha = q \stackrel{?}{\in} \mathbb{Q}$$
$$\left (e^{i\alpha}\right )^2 = e ^{i\cdot2\alpha}=\cos{2\alpha}+i\underbrace{{}\sin{2\alpha}}_{\neq 0} \notin \mathbb{R}$$
$$\left (e^{i\alpha}\right )^2 =(\underbrace{e^{i\cdot2\pi}}_1 )^q =1\in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: Manipulation with rational exponent in last step isn't allowed!