# Is $\sin(e)$ rational or irrational?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, real-numbers, transcendental-numbers

We know that $\pi$ and $e$ are transcendental numbers. Here $\sin(x)$ is a real trigonometric function. We know that $\sin(\pi)=0$ which is rational.
Now I am wondering to know that whether $\sin(e)$ is rational or irrational. In addition, if it is irrational then whether $\sin(e)$ is transcendental.

Comment: $\sin (e)$ is a linear combination of exponentials and therefore related to Schanuel's conjecture and Bakers theorem and its precursors: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture

Comment: @Avinash N:  I'm not certain about the downvotes, but one thing that is probably not obvious is that this is probably an open question (whether $\sin(e)$ is rational). People might vote to close or downvote if they think that the question is making an assumption that the answer should be known without realizing that it isn't.  Probably the only way to try to prevent it is to include more info in the question about why we might expect it to have an answer.

Comment: @AvinashN: Perhaps add the *open-problem* tag, given the recent comments?

Comment: @Krzysztof Myśliwiec: The answer to the question for which you have awarded the bounty is easy to answer: the answer is "no". Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398687/how-do-i-prove-that-frac1-pi-arccos1-3-is-irrational).

Comment: @TheoBendit Sorry for waiting- I have need 50+ Raputation again (as punishment for spending my own points...) . Nice feedback by I answered already my own question (which was removed- actually w/ a good reason). My answer: No, sample: $sin(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Answer (score 10):

** **comment** **
Mark says to use Schanuel's conjecture.  Here it is.

We know $e$ is real and nonzero, so the two numbers $ie$ and $1$ are linearly independent over the rationals.  From Schanuel's conjecture, we conclude that the transcendence degree of
$$
\mathbb Q(ie,1,e^{ie},e^1)
$$
is at least $2$.  But $1$ is algebraic, and $ie, e$ are algebraically related, so we conclude that $e^{ie}$ is transcendental.  Now
$$
\sin e = \frac{e^{ie}-e^{-ie}}{2i} = \frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{ie} - \frac{1}{e^{ie}}\right)
$$
so if $\sin e$ were algebraic, then solving a quadratic equation we would conclude that $e^{ie}$ would be algebraic.  Therefore,
$\sin e$ is transcentental.

Of course, Schanuel's conjecture is only a conjecture...

Comment: Thank you. Now I am going to thinking about it. How "e" and "ie" are algebraically related?

Comment: This doesn’t seem to work. I don’t see a way to get $ie$ from $e^{ie}$ algebraically over $\mathbb Q$

Comment: @StellaBiderman: Of course you cannot get $ie$ from $e^{ie}$ algebraically.  And I did not say that, anyway.

Comment: @StellaBiderman: You can get $ie$ from $e^1$, though.

Comment: I guess $(e/(ie))^4 = 1$ is an algebraic relation between $e$ and $ie$.