# $\cos(x)=\frac{1}{n}, n=2k+1, k\in \mathbb Z_+$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, contest-math

> Let $n\in N$ be odd. Prove that all solutions to the equation: $$
>  \cos{(x)}=\frac{1}{n}$$ are irrational. (Poland, 1966)

My work:

$$\frac{1}{3}=\max\Bigg\{\frac{1}{n}:n=2k+1, k\in \mathbb Z+\Bigg\}$$

$$\cos(x)=\frac{1}{n} \in\left\langle 0, \frac{1}{3}\right]$$$$\implies x\in\left\langle\frac{(4k-1)\pi}{2},-\arccos{\frac{1}{3}}+2k\pi\right]\cup\left[\arccos{\frac{1}{3}}+2k\pi,\frac{(4k+1)\pi}
{2} \right\rangle$$

Facts I took into account:

Apart from some powers of irrational roots, a product of two irrational numbers is most likely to be irrational.

If we subtract irrational numbers with different decimal parts or add two irrational numbers whose decimal parts aren't *'complementary'*, the result will be irrational as well.

$$x\in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q\implies x\ne\frac{m}{n}, \forall m\in \mathbb Z,\forall n\in \mathbb N$$

I considered proving by contradiction but didn't know how to realize it (I wanted to prove $M(m,n)\ne1$ and square $\arccos{\frac{1}{n}}$)

Another idea was to prove $\arccos{(kx)}, k\in \mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$.

There are many tools I didn't know which to choose.

Comment: That "Poland, 1966" means what?  This was in a contest for high-school students in Poland?  If so, I do not expect they know that result of Niven.  It would be interesting to find the proposed solution from 1966.

Comment: @GEdgar There is a book (translated from Croatian: Selected Elementary Math Tasks) , more of a collection of tasks brought together from various literature by prof. dr. Neven Elezović. There are no solutions in the book since it is intended for IMO preparings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a corollary [of a result by Ivan Niven](https://someclassicalmaths.wordpress.com/2009/07/17/nivens-proof-that-the-trigonometric-and-inverse-trigonometric-functions-are-irrational-for-rational-non-zero-arguments/): We have $$\cos(x)\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$$ whenever $x\in\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}$. Now you can simply take the contraposition.

---

Also, I am not sure if this classifies for a duplicate of [Why $\arccos(\frac{1}{3})$ is an irrational number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111288/why-arccos-frac13-is-an-irrational-number).

Comment: I think then it counts. I translated the task from a book and  searched for the same so I haven't seen it up to now. Thank you for the remark.

Comment: thank you for the link to the article, too.

Comment: @VerkhotsevaKatya You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem is more widely known than Niven's paper.

> (Special case) If $a$ is algebraic and nonzero, then $e^a$ is transcendental.

Suppose $\cos x = \frac{1}{3}$.  Then
$$
\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2} = \frac{1}{3}
$$
shows that $e^{ix}$ is algebraic (solving a quadratic equation).  Therefore, by L-W we conclude that $ix$ is transcendental.  And $i$ is algebraic so we have $x$ is transcendental.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if there is a way to do the cases $1/3,1/5,1/7,\dots$ that is more elementary than L-W or Niven, which do all rationals.

Comment: Seeing that this is from a contest I am 100% sure that there is some trick which doesn't use advanced results about trigonometric/exponential functions (but I hate finding these tricks )

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be like this ... if $\cos x = 1/3$, then repeatedly using addition formulas, half-angle formulas, etc., deduce for a certain $y$ (a function of $x$) that $\cos y = 0$ and therefore $y$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$.  And when we do this we do it so that we deduce $x$ is also algebraically related to $\pi$.